# What happens when you turn the header on/off in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

What happens when you turn the header on/off in sqlite? What does the header correspond to? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the following in sqlite3 command-line client...

> ```
> .headers on|off        Turn display of headers on or off
> ```

... enabling the feature outputs column names in a header row before printing out query results. Example:

```
sqlite> create table foo(bar,baz);
sqlite> insert into foo values(1,2);
sqlite> select * from foo;
1|2
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select * from foo;
bar|baz
1|2
```